# How can I unit-test this class in Android(it has static final variable)?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mocking

How can I test both methods if they work properly or not using unit-testing?

```
public class UserSession {

   public static final String SESSION_KEY = "sessionKey";

   @Nullable
   public String getSessionKey() {
      return Settings.getSharedPreferences().getString(SESSION_KEY, null);
   }

   private void setSessionKey(String key) {
      Settings.putString(SESSION_KEY, key);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Android but the class looks like a standard Java class. Therefore I think a test like the following would work.

```
public class UserSessionTest {
    private final UserSession userSession = new UserSession();

    @Test
    public void sessionKeyIsNullByDefault() {
        String key = userSession.getSessionKey();
        assertNull(key);
    }

    @Test
    public void sessionKeyCanBeChanged() {
        userSession.setSessionKey("dummy key");
        assertEquals("dummy key", userSession.getSessionKey());
    }
}
```